# cannot get session value in different events

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, session

I'm using two different events controller pre dispatch and controller post dispatch.I have set customvalue using  catalogsession in predispatch event and try to get the value in post dispatch event.but the session value  returns null.If I try to get value in  predispatch event.It returns correctly.

predispatch observer

```
protected $registry;

protected $request;

protected $catalogSession;

protected $filterValue;

protected $context;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    Registry $registry
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->context = $context;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    
}



public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $full_action_name = $this->request->getFullActionName();

    if ($full_action_name != 'catalog_category_view') {
        return;
    }
    $param = $this->request->getParams();
    unset($param['mAjax']);
    $ab =$this->catalogSession->setFilter($param);
   var_dump($ab); 
   return $this;
```

post dispatch observer

```
protected $request;

private $registry;

protected $context;

protected $catalogSession;

protected $FilterCookie;

public function __construct(
    Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    
)
{    $this->request = $request;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    $this->context = $context;
  
    
}

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
    $full_action_name = $this->request->getFullActionName();
    
    //$layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    if ($full_action_name != 'catalog_category_view') {
        return;
    }
   $a =  $this->catalogSession->getFilter();
 var_dump($a); exit();
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code?

Comment: @Joao71 updated my observer

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are trying to store is sent in the $request object. You can get it on the post dispatch.

if you want you can store the value in a custom variable to make sure it does not conflic with other variable sin the HTTP Header.

Example:

**predispatch observer**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $full_action_name = $this->request->getFullActionName();

    if ($full_action_name != 'catalog_category_view') {
        return;
    }
    $param = $this->request->getParams();
    unset($param['mAjax']);
   // $ab =$this->catalogSession->setFilter($param);
   $this->request->setPostValue('test_param', $param);
   var_dump($ab); 
   return $this;
}
```

**postdispatch observer**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
    $full_action_name = $this->request->getFullActionName();
    
    //$layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    if ($full_action_name != 'catalog_category_view') {
        return;
    }
   //$a =  $this->catalogSession->getFilter();
     $test_param = $this->request->getPostValue('test_param');
 var_dump($a); exit();
}
```

let me know if you need any further assistance and don't forget to mark as answer if this solved your problem :)